# Emacs: How to change orgmode calender language?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I insert timestamp by `C-c .`, I do not get a day in the English language.

> <2019-03-19 tis>

Calendar entries are in English e.g Su Mo Tu We... but when inserted as timestamp they show up in a different language.

Is it possible to change the calendar language in orgmode?

Answer (score 0):

The display depends on the LOCALE settings of your system. If you cannot change that try:

[this emacs stack exchange answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19611/17548)

That also links to:

[emacs wiki calander-localization](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CalendarLocalization)

Here is a German language example from the above link:

```
 (setq calendar-week-start-day 1
          calendar-day-name-array ["Sonntag" "Montag" "Dienstag" "Mittwoch"
                                   "Donnerstag" "Freitag" "Samstag"]
          calendar-month-name-array ["Januar" "Februar" "März" "April" "Mai"
                                     "Juni" "Juli" "August" "September"
                                     "Oktober" "November" "Dezember"])
```